# Simple MediaWiki extension debugging

Tags: debugging, mediawiki

I am trying to write my very first MediaWiki extension and need some way to debug it. What is the simplest way to do it? Showing a message, logging into a file etc. would be fine. I just want to slowly progress over the code and see where it breaks and what the content of a variable is.

I've tried (from http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Useful_debugging_functions)

```
// ...somewhere in your code
if ( true ) {
    wfDebugLog( 'myext', 'Something is not right: ' . print_r( 'asdf', true ) );
}
```

in extensions/myext/myext.php and added to LocalSettings.php

```
require_once( 'extensions/myext/myext.php' );
# debugging on
$wgDebugLogGroups = array(
     'myext'     => 'extensions/myext/myextension.log'
);
```

but then my Wiki doesn't work at all (error 500). With the above code removed from myext.php everything's fine (with $wgExtensionCredits in myext.php, I can see myext in the Special:Version).

Is it the right thing to do (then what is the mistake) or is there a better/simpler way to start with?

Answer (score 2):

500 means you have a syntax error or wrong configuration somewhere.  Have you followed the instructions at [Manual:How to debug](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug) and turned on PHP logging, so you can at least see what is causing the error?  Alternatively, take a look at your Apache server log.

Also, you'll want to turn on debugging *before* you load your own extension!

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point! We are having some problems with the wiki installation in general at the moment. May be there is some overlap between my modifications and the overall functioning of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to `LocalSettings.php` for debugging:

```
error_reporting( -1 );
ini_set( 'display_startup_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

$wgShowExceptionDetails=true;
$wgDebugToolbar=true;
$wgShowDebug=true;
$wgDevelopmentWarnings=true;
$wgDebugDumpSql = true;
$wgDebugLogFile = '/tmp/debug.log';
$wgDebugComments = true;
$wgEnableParserCache = false;
$wgCachePages = false;
```

You can log debug messages with `wfDebug();`

Learn more at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Structured_logging/en